# Polymer 1.4.0 to 1.7.0, global :root styles no longer work

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have some styles that are meant to apply anywhere, including deep inside components. They're defined like this:

```
<style id="base-css" is="custom-style">
    :root .primary { 
        color: red; 
    }
</style>
```

The result was that if I had, for example a `<span class="primary">` anywhere, no matter how deep inside a Polymer component, it'd always apply. In fact, inspecting this span shows that the style was rewritten as:

```
:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope):root .primary { 
    color: red;
}
```

---

Since I've updated my Polymer to 1.7.0, this no longer works. Styles defined this way no longer penetrate into components, and only work outside them. Adding a span with `.primary` to body and inspecting it shows that the style is now rewritten as:

```
html .primary:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) { 
    color: red;
}
```

Which, of course, wouldn't work inside a component, since all inside elements have `.style-scope` on them.

I read 1.7.0 release notes, and tried replacing `:root` with `html`, with exactly the same result.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can get this to work again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating style hooks using CSS custom properties

You can tweak internal styles if you provide styling hooks using CSS custom properties. You create "style placeholders" inside the element that you can override from the main page.

Inside the main page:

```
<style>
  base-css {
    --primary: red;
  }
</style>
```

Inside the element:

```
    <style>
        :host([background]) {
          // Use --primary is not define, use #9E9E9E 
          background: var(--primary, #9E9E9E);
        }
    </style>
```

Documentation

[Using CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

[Shadow DOM v1: Self-Contained Web Components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylefromoutside)

Comment: Thanks for a suggested workaround, but this doesn't quite achieve what I am trying to do. The goal is to be able to use global classes inside shady DOM.